# How can I recognize a pointer in ontouchlistener?

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm developing a program(phone as a mouse) using multitouch on android 2.2. I just use ontouch method of ontouchlistener. It seems that ontouch is a event oriented method that it can not remember a specific pointer.

For example, I got a finger down on the screen, say pointer A, then another finger down on the screen, say pointer B. How can I recognize which one of A and B is up when there is ACTION_POINTER_UP or ACTION_UP event?

Hope I'm clear enough. I haven't tried the gesturedetector yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACTION_DOWN - primary pointer. (first finger) has gone down

ACTION_POINTER_DOWN - secondary pointer. (second finger) gone down

ACTION_MOVE - change in pressed location

ACTION_POINTER_UP = secondary pointer released

ACTION_UP - primary pointer released

good luck.

Comment: The problem is, the first released pointer will make the ACTION_POINTER_UP event no matter whether it is the first finger down.

Comment: even if there is just one finger? if theres 2 the secondary pointer event will get raised first..

Comment: one finger will only cause ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, 2 fingers always in an ACTION_DOWN- ACTION_POINTER_DOWN-ACTION_POINTER_UP -ACTION_UP order

Comment: isnt that supposed to be correct? cause your second finger will be up first isn't it?

Comment: I've tried it, the events have nothing to do with the actual pointer, only in a time order.

Comment: so what you wanna do is to know which pointer belongs to a and which belongs to b? you can try using getPointerId() to get the first pointer that is down and assign it accordingly. the first pointer that is down will have the value 0. check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId(int)

Comment: Finally i handled it by getActionIndex(), of course using poniter ID will also help